# Upload videos in Laravel project

Tags: php, database, laravel, upload

I am having trouble when I try to upload video/movie to my site. It doesn't save the video in the database, but it makes a folder 'movie' in my files with that video in it like it's supposed to. Also I edited my php.ini file for size requirements and session that I made says that it uploaded.  Here is my code

View:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=> 'MovieController@store', 'files' => true]) !!}
  <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('movie_name', 'Enter Movie Name:') !!} <br>
     {!! Form::text('movie_name', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('uploaded_path', 'Select Movie:') !!} <br>
     {!! Form::file('uploaded_path', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('actor_id', 'Actors:') !!}
     {!! Form::select('actor_id[]', $actors, null, ['class'=>'form-control js-example-basic-multiple', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('category_id', 'Category:') !!}
     {!! Form::select('category_id[]', $categories, null, ['class'=>'form-control js-example-basic-multiple', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!}
</div>
```

MovieRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'movie_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'uploaded_path' => 'mimetypes:video/avi,video/mpeg,video/mp4|required'
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```
public function store(MovieRequest $request)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        if ($request->hasFile('uploaded_path')) {
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('uploaded_path')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('uploaded_path')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $filename. '_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            $path = $request->file('uploaded_path')->storeAs('public/movies/', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'novideo.mp4';
        }

        $movie = new Movie;
        $movie->movie_name = $request->input('movie_name');
        $movie->uploaded_path = $fileNameToStore;
        $movie->actors()->attach($request->input('actor_id'));
        $movie->categories()->attach($request->input('category_id'));
        $movie->save();

        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
    }
    Session::flash('success', 'A movie was successfully UPLOADED in the database!');
    return redirect()->route('movies.index');
}
```

Comment: So `$movie` doesn't exist - it is not defined anywhere - and even if it did you never do `$movie->save()`.

Comment: I edited post, it works now but I now have many to many relationship attached and now they don't work. works when I upload but it doesn't attach actors and categories. It shows in pivot tables that movie_id is null but categorry_id and actor_id shows correct ids. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t forget to add:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to movie field.